# Does pinned post in a chat room get moderator attention?

Tags: support, chat, chat-pins

I tried to pin [this message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19328864#19328864) again. But I got an alert:

> You have already voted, but the voting has been cleared by a moderator

So, does a pinned message get moderator attention every time when a message post gets pinned. or someone may have flagged this message post?

Comment: @jonsca this is not related to moderator tools. Any user with 20 rep can become room owner and pin messages.

Comment: @sha The tag was re-added in the rollback.  I stepped back because I had misinterpreted the situation.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @jonsca oh, didn't even notice it was a rollback, it appeared you added the tag. Cheers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither, that message is just a little imprecise. The "moderator" in this case is the automatic job that removes pins. Pinned messages are limited to being pinned for 14 days.

Comment: Can messages pinned twice?

Comment: @rekire no. And also, balpha, this message is also displayed when a room owners clears the pins/stars manually.

Comment: looks like I have got no choice anyway xD.

Comment: @balpha Why a post can be pinned for a limited period ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Because nobody unpins anything manually, and leaving pins forever eventually leads to a "starred" list that contains not a single recent star, just a ton of old irrelevant pins.

Comment: @rekire One person cannot pin a message twice, but if you pinned a message then it can still be pinned by another person later.

Comment: Did you implement this because of this "MY GOD, IT'S FULL OF STARS!" in tavern...? :P

Comment: @balpha Just want to note that "nobody unpins anything manually" is definitely false.

Comment: In any case, this message clearly needs to be changed to something similar to: "This message has already been pinned, previously, and may not be pinned again."

Comment: @balpha: Okay, so why prevent *re-pinning*? If it is going to be auto-unpinned in 2 weeks again anyway?

Comment: @balpha: also, please make the error message clearer. And not silent when trying to re-pin in the transcript. And make the message not show as pinned when it has been auto-unpinned.